# Calculate the length of the adjacent side when $\cos \angle{BAC} = \frac{3\sqrt{109}}{109}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am learning basic trigonometry. I've been doing this exercise:

[image]

And I am told that

$$\cos \angle {BAC} = \frac{3\sqrt{109}}{109}$$

Well, the $?$ is the adjacent side of $\angle{BAC}$, so I am working with the adjacent and the hypotenuse. This means cosine (adjacent over hypotenuse). In other words:

$$\cos \angle {BAC} = \frac{?}{\sqrt{109}} = \frac{3\sqrt{109}}{109}$$

All I have to do is to multiply both sides by $\sqrt{109}$ and I should end up with

$$? = \frac{3}{109}$$

However the exercise insists that the answer is just plain $3$. Why is that?

Comment: Your multiplying went a bit wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the cosine is adjacent over hypotenuse (from SOH-CAH-TOA). So $$\cos BAC = \frac{3\sqrt{109}}{109}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{109}}=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$$
So the adjacent side of triangle $BAC$ has length $3$. (Also, the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{109}$, which is confirmed by your image.)

Comment: @Vil Note that $$\frac{3\sqrt{109}}{109} = \frac{3\sqrt{109}}{(\sqrt{109})^2} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{109}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You know $AB = \sqrt {109}$ and 
$\cos BAC=\dfrac{3 \sqrt{109}}{109}=\dfrac{adjacent }{hypotenuse}=\dfrac{AC}{AB}=\dfrac{AC}{\sqrt {109}}$. So, 
$\dfrac{3 \sqrt{109}}{109}=\dfrac{AC}{\sqrt {109}}$ 
$AC=3 \sqrt{109}\sqrt{109}/109$$=3 \cdot 109/109 = 3$